# Is there any solution exist for screenrecorder android app that only record specific app or game but do not record any overlay or notification

Tags: android, mobile

I want to create a android app for screen recording. I only want to record specific app or game and don't want to record any overlay or notification that comes when recording any specific game or application

Comment: You can mute system sound while recording and give priority to your app sound using package name or something like most of the music player do

Comment: Not sound bro...I am asking about screen overlay

Comment: during recording when any other screen appear it should not be recorded

Comment: @JamalAhmad Did you ever find the answer to this question?

Comment: @Doh09 Did'nt found anything it was a deadend

Answer (score 0):

That kinda difficult but you can use PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS permission and check using package name which app is opened and turn on and off recording according to it. after that merge all the videos into one. I guess this is the only way to do it.